# `import pygame` shows no errors even when pygame is not installed

Tags: python, installation, pygame

I've been installing, uninstalling, and reinstalling pygame because there's a program that I've been trying to run (that uses pygame). However whenever I've installed pygame, the program doesn't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\en\snake.py", line 28, in <module>
    class Segment(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sprite'
```

(Pygame is not installed when I receive this error supposedly)

What's really confusing me though is that when I type `import pygame` in normally in IDLE, I get no errors even when I just uninstalled it.

- Windows 8 64 bit
- Python 3.4.3
- Pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.4.msi (pygame file name)
- Python is installed on C Drive (`C:\Python34`)
- Whenever Pygame was installed, it was on the D drive
- Have Python directory added to Path

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7njoT.png) a screenshot of a video tutorial I was following, and it shows there are two installation paths. And [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM5SJ.png) mine, which only shows one path. I'm not sure if this is a big deal, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: The way I usually import modules is by placing them in C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages. I have never heard of installing on D: (which sounds like a flash drive).

Comment: @bcdan It's a second hard drive, sorry should have clarified.

Comment: I think that the module needs to be installed in the drive that python is installed on. So if `C:/Python34` is where Python is installed, the module needs to be in the `Lib/site-packages` folder in the same directory. That is the default directory.

Comment: @bcdan When I install Pygame it only allows me to select one installation path, which is on `D:/`, could I just copy/paste my files into `Lib/site-packages`? I've already tried this actually, and when I type `import pygame` I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/f7rqHod.png)

Comment: When I installed pygame, I simply did a drag-and-drop into the folder. I think that should work fine. I don't think pygame _requires_ installment. However, _I_ use Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Open your python interpreter and `import pygame`
Then you can print pygame to see exactly what is being loaded, should be something like: `<module 'pygame' from '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py'>`
(repeat the above step until it fails importing pygame),
Close your prompt and install pygame. Try executing it again. Should the problem persist, you can edit some file in the game you are trying to run and add two lines: `import sys` and `print sys.path` and check the list of paths to make sure that there is not some other pygame installation somewhere bundled with the game that is being used instead of your installed pygame.

Comment: I can not even type `import pygame` and *not* get an error message. I think the problem is adding Pygame to my `PYTHONPATH`, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Modification of Josep Valls's answer:

You will need to change `sys.path`. This can be accomplished with the following code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('''directory where pygame is''')
import pygame
```

The `sys.path` variable tell Python where to look for modules. By adding a path by append, you are telling Python to look for imported modules there. After that pointer is made, you can import pygame.